# Unknown module(s) in QT: declarative

Tags: qt

Sorry, this may be a dumb question, but I'm totally new in QT, I just need to run a project and Log some data.

I installed Qt "qt-unified-windows-x86-2.0.3-2-online", open the project and then click on configure, and then I got this error:
Unknown module(s) in QT: declarative

which wont let me compile the code. Everything else looks fine.
From researching I get that I may lack some libraries, I'm using windows, How do I get the proper library in windows? which is the library I need?

I'm using "Qt Creator user the kit Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MinGW 32bit."

Thank you.

I'm downloading linux, a live version, to try to run the code in there

Comment: Don't spam language tags! C is not C++ is not C.

Comment: what is the project you are trying to run?

Comment: Hi @Mike .  Its an android app, which communicates to a ble device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error occurs when trying to build a project that depends on the deprecated [QtDeclarative module](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-porting-qt5.html#qtdeclarative-module-in-qt-5) on Qt version 5.6 and later, as the module was [removed in version 5.6](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew56.html#removed-functionality).

The source code for the module is still available you can compile it from source. Or you can install a [Qt version below Qt 5.6](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/) to build the project.

Comment: Yes.  It works,  I got an old Qt version and it compiles.  Thank you.

Comment: @LearningCharlito, hi , how you get old qt version?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have declarative library installed somehow, [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) it is recommended to use a command-line utility named windeployqt, something like

```
windeployqt -declarative
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @bipll for your suggestion, it makes perfect sense.
this command throws Error : Please specify the binary or folder.             

According to the docs.    
The simplest way to use windeployqt is to add the bin directory of your Qt installation (e.g. <QT_DIR\bin>) to the PATH variable **(Done)**  and then run:   windeployqt <path-to-app-binary>  **what is this path-to-app-binary?** app-binary of what?   Thank you

Comment: The link in the answer is about deployment. the problem in the question occurs when running qmake before the actual project is built.